# How to load three series from CSV into Highcharts via options.series.data.push

Tags: jquery, csv, highcharts

I am trying to figure out how I can add three different items from a CSV file into a Highcharts graph. One of them should be displayed as a column; two as lines.

So far, I have this ([here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/tf81ayt4/1/)):

```
    plotOptions: 
    {
        series: 
        {
            connectNulls: true,
            shadow: false,
            marker: 
            {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },  
    series: [{
        name: 'Yearly mass balance',
        data: [],
        color: '#7994d9',
        negativeColor: '#ff6c7f'
    },{
        name: '10 year average',
        data: [],
        color: '#ffa27c',
        type: 'spline'
    },{
        name: 'Polynomial',
        data: [],
        color: '#093ad9',
        type: 'spline',
    }]
};

// data is variable from $.get()
$.get('graph_glaciers_3.csv', function(data)
{   
    var series = {
        data: []
    };

    var temp = []

    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // For each line, split the record into seperate attributes
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
    {
        var items = line.split(',');

        if (lineNo !== 0) 
        {
            var xValue = +items[0],
            v1 = parseFloat(items[1]),
            v2 = parseFloat(items[2]),
            v3 = parseFloat(items[3]);

            if (!isNaN(v1)) 
            {
                options.series[0].data.push([xValue,v1]);
                options.series[1].data.push([xValue,v2]);
                options.series[2].data.push([xValue,v3])
            }
        }
    });


    // Push the completed series
    //options.series.push(series);

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

But that's not yet working. Not sure why. I wasn't sure about the specifications in the "series" object in the Highcharts code; and neither about the "options.series[].data.push"-array. Tried to find answers around, but didn't find anything.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Your chart looks almost ok, you had some small mistakes in your code. I have changed your example and I think it is working now: http://jsfiddle.net/tf81ayt4/2/
You had problem with your yAxis as well. You had big min,max and tickInterval values and that is the reason why your columns was not visible - they were too small.

Comment: Thanks. The big numbers were a left-over, sorry for that. The other additional problem (on my server) was the NULL values respectively empty values like "1980,200,," - which I only could solve via deleting these rows - see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/tf81ayt4/3/).

Comment: Ok, was a problem with the parseFloat of the values. A NULL value can't evidently be converted into a float... [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/tf81ayt4/5/) is the working version.